# Shorter way of testing for null and undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a book that says that while it's possible to test whether a variable is defined and has a value by doing:

```
if(myVar != null && myVar != undefined) {
  ...
}
```

this is considered “poor style”, and that since both `null` and `undefined` are falsey values, we can more easily check if a variable has a value by using the more concise `if` construct

```
if(myVar) {
  ...
}
```

But this confuses me, because while it’s true that `null` and `undefined` are falsey values, they are not the *only* falsey values. In other words, it seems to me that the former `if` statement says, "run the code as long as the variable isn't null or undefined, whereas the latter `if` statement is saying, "run the code as long as the variable isn't falsey." Supposing `myVar == 0`, then the former `if` statement would run, but the latter `if` statement would not. Therefore these two `if` statements are not equivalent. Am I wrong?

EDIT: Here's a screen grab if you want to see their exact wording:
[image: testing for null and undefined]

Comment: **Yes** both are not replica of each other. This is all you want?

Comment: You are right and it is a matter of choice. When you write the code, consider the most common use cases.

Comment: There is no other way to find out if the variable is null or undefined. Definitely the two snippets that you have shown are not the same.
If you `myvar` variable is a number then you can use `isNaN` function.

Comment: @Manwal No, it's not all I want. Given that they are not "replica" (equivalent) of one another, why is the book stating that it's OK to use one in place of the other?

Comment: @yroc Are you sure that's exactly what your book says? If so the book is wrong.

Comment: Yes in some manner book is Right because if you are considering only `null` and `undefined` both results same but if you are considering million values, only then million cases would come.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I added a screenshot of the book page if you want to have a look.

Comment: @yroc Yes it's wrong, for example clearly `var item = 0` is a defined value.

Comment: I'd get another book

Comment: @DavePile Haha, I'm thinking the same thing, but it's for a course so I'm kind of stuck with it :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if the variable is either `null` or `undefined`, use the not single equal operator checking for `null`.

```
if (myVar != null) {

}
```

However, it's always best practice to use triple equals to be more explicit.

```
if (!(myVar === null || typeof myVar === 'undefined')) {

}
```

Comparisons

```
(undefined == null) => true
(null == null) => true
(undefined === null) => false
(null === null) => true
(0 == null) => false
(0 == undefined) => false
(0 === null) => false
(0 === undefined) => false
(false == null) => false
(false == undefined) => false
(false === null) => false
(false === undefined) => false
(null) => false
(undefined) => false
(0) => false
(false) => false
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xk9L3yuz/3/**

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a short way. You first need to check for undefined before null, because

```
!myVar
```

makes the assumption that myVar is previously defined, and will throw

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myVar is not defined
```

in the event that you never defined that variable.

This check is only required if you're pulling data from some external source and are unsure if the variable exists. If you already defined it somewhere in your code and are for instance waiting for user input to set it, you can take the shortcut of

```
!myVar
```

simply because you *know* it's already defined because you did it earlier in the code.